# How do squashed commits compare to non-squashed?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-squash

Suppose I have a `master` branch, and a `dev` branch. After working in the `dev` branch, I squash and merge it into master

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash dev 
git commit
```

This makes a new commit, right? But it seems like running `git checkout dev; git merge master` spits out `already up-to-date`. I'm not complaining, but how is this possible. There should be a *new* commit that conflicts with all the squashed ones, shouldn't there?

Edit: There's no error, I just want to know *why* there's no error.

Comment: You can always check which commits do you really have with `git log master` or `git log dev` at any moment, no need to assume anything. As for your exact steps, I do not confirm, for me it merges. It may do it without reporting conflict if your changes on both sidea are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, it does merge, but I don't know how that's possible.

Comment: Yes, if both sides do same change then it's just accepted without reporting conflict.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I thought changes from multiple commits on the same lines, even identical changes ,would make a conflict.  If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if both sides do same change then it's just accepted without reporting conflict.

– max630

This is not how I thought merging worked. I assumed multiple commits modifying the same file would at the same location would always cause a conflict. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The branch you have checked out is the one you are modifying. To bring changes from dev to master checkout master and merge dev.

Comment: That's what I do in the first and second line (`git checkout master` and `git merge --squash dev`)